# How to remove an element from a vector who starts with given value

Tags: c++, string

Given a vector of strings and a string, what's the easiest way to delete each element of the vector whose string starts with the given string?

For example say `vector<string> ToProcess` is populated and you want to remove each element that starts with `string done = "123xyz"?
There will only be one match.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove

Comment: What's you take on the issue?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I can't understand your English.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was indeed unclear. The question I wanted to raise was what *you* did in order to resolve the issue. The point I wanted to make was that your question shows no effort on your side which was also the reason I downvoted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that there will only be one match, it is actually a bit tricky to use the STL for this.  Instead of using `std::remove_if` you need to use `std::find_if` to locate the one value to remove, then overwrite that value with the last value in the vector, then `pop_back()`.  Doing all this takes a couple extra lines of code, but gives you optimal performance which you won't get otherwise (because `remove_if` won't stop after finding one, and some other ways will try to erase from the middle which requires moving the back half of the vector down).

To use `find_if` you must first implement a predicate which does "startswith" for strings, like this:

```
struct StartsWith
{
  StartsWith(string prefix) : _prefix(prefix) {}
  bool operator()(const string& value) { /*...*/ }
private:
  string _prefix;
};
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work when `find_if()` (and `remove_if()`) take unary functions that get passed the value of the item iterated over? Now the function can't be aware of `done` and doesn't know what should be matched against.

Comment: You're right, those functions do take unary predicates.  But they do not take only unary "functions," they also take "function objects."  What this means is that you implement a class or struct which has a `bool operator()(const std::string& str)` which does the startswith comparison, but you also give the class a constructor taking the string you want to start with, and a private member storing the same.  Now your unary function gets the value being matched, but also has access (because it is a member function) to what you want to find.  This is a pretty common technique with `find_if` etc.

Comment: interesting, here it claims `find_if()` only takes unary functions. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

Comment: It says "This can either be a function pointer or a function object."  What I have described is a "function object" and it is still a "unary function object" it just happens to be stateful as well.  I'm sorry the terminology can be confusing sometimes, welcome to C++.  ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks. When compiling it complains about the use of `operator`, I think it still needs a name. Do you have any idea how to make the code cleaner since it seems extraneous to give a name to the function in the struct?

Comment: Sorry I forgot one set of parens in my example.  Added it now.  The name of the operator is exactly `operator ()`.  It doesn't have another name; some people call it the "function call operator."